# Punctuation in equations

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, punctuation

My document will contain a lot of equations, and as usual in that case I would like to use "punctuation" in the equations, like commas, colons, periods/full stops, semicolons, etc.

Is there a special way to correctly do that? Now I just type these characters at the end of the equations, but as it's in math mode maybe there is a better way that improve the spacing, etc.

I also read about `\colon`, `\ldotp`. What do they do that the normal "characters" don't?

Comment: `\colon` changes the spacing for use in defining a function: `f \colon A \to B`, it would look funny if used as a colon serving its normal text purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can key in the punctuations marks as usual.  As Seamus writes in his comment, macros like `\colon` are for punctuation marks that are being used as mathematical relations rather than punctuation.

Sentence punctuation should not appear inside of *inline* mathematics.  For *displayed* mathematics, I think it's safe to say it's a matter of style.  See ["For formal articles, should a displayed equation be followed by a punctuation to conform to the language grammar?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7542/for-formal-articles-should-a-displayed-equation-be-followed-by-a-punctuation-to)
I'm in the camp of no sentence punctuation in display math; it's just distracting.  *De gustibus non est disputandum.*

So for example:

```
If $a$ and $b$ are the lengths of the legs of a right triangle 
and $c$ is the length of the hypotenuse, then $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, or:
\[
   c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}
\]
This amazing relation is known as the \textbf{Pythagorean Theorem}.
```

Comment: I agree it is a matter of style, but I'm a bit more on the other side :p Anyway I just have to use normal punctuation marks in that case. Is there something special to do with the spacing ? Like `\,;` to force a larger spacing ?

Comment: @Cedric H.: If you wouldn't put spacing after a word before a semicolon, why would you put it after an equation?  Just my opinion.

Comment: @Matthew Leingang: Good point :p

Comment: @Mathew Leingang: in some land (Switzerland for example) you must put a thinspace before a semicolon. So the question stays.

Comment: @Matsaya: in such case, wouldn't you use the `babel` package that would insert the space before the semicolon automatically?  Would that still happen in math mode?

Comment: @Matsaya: Interesting.  Then let me broaden to say I think it should be the same with (inline) equations as it is with natural language sentences.

Comment: @Jan Hlavacek, Babel inserts a space automatically in text mode, but not in math mode (neither inline or display)