# "$$...$$." has the dot on the wrong line; How to punctuate correctly?

Tags: math-mode, punctuation

I like to use the `$$\sum S_{i}$$` or something similar. But I get the dot `.` or the comma `,` placed in an awkward position. I work around this problem sometimes by using `$ \sum S$`, but this is not good to stress things. Then again to be more specific, I use

```
\begin{equation}
...
\end{equation}
```

but I have noted that I overuse the latter so I want to somehow have the comma typeset the correct way when I use `$$ something $$`. Please note that in some languages comma is used to separate connected clauses -- this differs from English! But, suppose I want to use `$$....$$, where ...` or how can I write `...in other words it means $$...$$.` where I have used the period. Using it as-is, it comes after the equation on the next line. How can I fix this?

In the example below, how can I fix the comma or the dot?

```
$$\sum S$$, where I have nothing really to say in this example.
```

It is `$$\sum S$$`.

Comment: Related questions: [For formal articles, should a displayed equation be followed by a punctuation to conform to the language grammar ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7542/3954) and [Punctuation in equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11821/3954). And you shouldn't use `$$...$$` in LaTeX documents; you should use `\[...\]` instead.

Comment: @hhh: I edited your post and used some mark-up (by using backticks) to highlight what you're after. Feel free to roll back or re-edit if I misinterpreted your original question. Do so by clicking on the `edit` link at the bottom of your post.

Comment: The `$$...$$` vs. `\[...\]` matter has actually been explained on here already: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Gonzalo mentioned in his comment, you should use `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$` for displayed math equations. Consider reading more about this (and other LaTeX2e tabu's) by viewing the [`l2tabu` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf).

Regardless, you have two choices, depending on whether you write a displaystyle `\[...\]` or textstyle `\(...\)` (or `$...$`) math expression:

- In `displaystyle` math mode, everything after the `\]` is flushed to the next paragraph, including punctuation. So, to have punctuation contained with the displayed equation, just include it as you would normally within text. Here's an example:

  ```
  This is some paragraph text, and you can see that
  \[
    a^2+b^2=c^2.
  \]
  Here is the next paragraph.
  ```

  [image: Punctuation in display math]

  Although I added some whitespace to accentuate the displaystyle math format, this is not really necessary. That is, the following example will produce the same result:

  ```
  This is more paragraph text, and you can see that \[a^2+b^2=c^2.\] Here is the next paragraph.
  ```

  However, even though the output is perhaps the main purpose of a (La)TeX project, readability of code adds to its longevity.
- In textstyle math you can do the same as above, although it is better to use:

  ```
  This is some paragraph text, and you can see that $a^2+b^2=c^2$.
  Here is the next sentence.
  ```

  [image: Punctuation in text math]

  If you do want `displaystyle` math in `textstyle` math mode, then you can force that using:

  ```
  This is some paragraph text, and you can see that $\displaystyle\sum S_i$.
  Here is the next sentence.
  ```

  [image: displaystyle equation in textstyle math mode]

  Note, however, that your interline spacing will be off. Or, even if it is maintained, there may be some overlap with symbols that are extensible in `displaystyle` math mode.