# Ending sentences in an aligned equation

Tags: formatting, punctuation

This is more of a general "mathematical english/punctuation" question, but I figure TeX users will know the answer.  The following sentence seems natural:

```
We define the $xyz$ constant via $xyz=\int_0^\infty f(y)dy$.
```

Note the period at the end, which is of course correct.  What if I decide to align the equation for $xyz$?

```
We define the $xyz$ constant via 

\begin{align}
    xyz=\int_0^\infty f(y)dy 
\end{align}
```

Should I still place a period at the end of this sentence (in the aligned equation)?  Is it considered bad form to end sentences in the middle of aligned equations like this?

Thanks!

Comment: I certainly would recommend putting a period there. I know many textbooks do not do that for displayed equations, but I feel that math should really have a sentence structure and hence my preference for the period.

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): [“$$…$$.” has the dot on the wrong line; How to punctuate correctly?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29849/5764); [Period after math-mode equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32853/5764)

Comment: @Werner or indeed here:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7542/for-formal-articles-should-a-displayed-equation-be-followed-by-a-punctuation-to, which I just now found.